# Syncing Data from local database to online database SQL Server and VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Is there a way of syncing a local database to online database ?

Lets say, I have a local database with a bunch of data stored. When I click a button all data from my local database will be sync to my online database. I am using SQL Server 2012 and VB.Net.

Thank you.

Comment: entire database ?

Comment: @Squirrel, not the entire database, just for a selected table and selected data date.

Comment: There's no magic to it.  Query the local database and then save the data to the main database.  It's just like any other data access.

Comment: What is the functionality of the online db ? does replication works for you ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @jmcilhinney Im thinking of selecting data from a local database table and insert the selected data to my online database table.

Comment: then just use `LINKED SERVER` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That's pretty much it.  You can use a data adapter to load the local data and then you can probably use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert it into the primary database, assuming that it's all new records.  If you need to update as well as insert then a data adapter would be required for the second stage too.  In the latter case, I'd be inclined to set `AcceptChangesOnFill` to `False` for the source adapter and then use an "upsert" in the `InsertCommand` of the destination adapter.

Comment: Since I am completely new to this, I'll try all of the recommendations. I really appreciate it . Thank you.

Comment: @Squirrel, My query works great on SQL Server management studio but when I execute the query in my vb.net program, an execution timeout expired has occurred. ., I have already set execution timeout = 0 as well as the connection timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Squirrel recommend to use LINKED SERVER , a built-in feature of SQL Server Management Studio (I am using SSMS 2012) to enable the Database Engine to execute a Transact-SQL statement that includes tables in another instance of SQL Server, or another database product such as Oracle. see [linked-servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017). I am able to synchronize data using queries.

I achieve inserting data from local database to online database using the following queries:

```
INSERT INTO [linkedserverhostname].databasename.dbo.tablename
SELECT * From dbo.tablename Where Convert(Date, StartTime) = '08/26/2018'
```

EXPLANATION:

Insert into

```
INSERT INTO [linkedserverhostname].databasename.dbo.tablename
```

whatever the value of this select statement

```
SELECT * From dbo.tablename Where Convert(Date, StartTime) = '08/26/2018'
```

Same as the update and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [SQL Server Replication Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017).